# Services on windows using Visual C++ 6.0

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I need to create a service on windows using Visual C++ 6.0 .
I am not familier with services so I read in the msdn site.

Can someone send me likns to agood sites explaining (with example) how to create service using Visual C++ 6.0 (prefer with examples) ?

Comment: Get away from VC6, and _certainly_ skip it for new code. It's obsolete and no longer maintained.

Answer (score 2):

You can use ATL to build a service in VC6. Try the ATL wizard, and let it generate the service stub for you, then you can flesh it out with proper functionality.

That said, the ATL framework's service support isn't great (at least wasn't in VC6), and will give you a service that's tailored to exposing COM objects.

There's a great book on services, called Professional NT Services:
[http://www.amazon.com/Professional-NT-Services-Kevin-Miller/dp/1861001304/ref=pd_sim_b_3](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1861001304)

See if you can get it used.

Comment: Is the ATL version from VC6 compatible with DEP?

Comment: As I recall it, ATL only uses thunking for its windowing classes, and I believe DEP was hard-wired to recognize ATL's thunk and not trigger on it. There was some discussion on the ATL list with the libraries team about this, but the archives have disappeared.